# transfer file out from hdfs to remote server

Tags: hadoop, redhat, rsyslog

I want to transfer files out from HDFS to local filesystem of a different server which is not in hadoop cluster but in the network using rsyslog or syslog-ng

can any one help on this. No curl or wget should be used. 
 or is there any better way other than rsyslog or syslog-ng?

Comment: Did you tried Apache nifi ? to pull the data from HDFS to local. In that you need to mention the hadoop conf (core and hdfs) and download them locally using put file processor. 
Reference - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/54099/how-can-we-fetch-files-from-a-hdfs-to-local-machin.html

Comment: Karthik- thanks for responding on this. Currently nifi is not available in the cluster